# VLC pixelates a 1080p video on my laptop

Tags: video, vlc

I'm having trouble playing a video I encoded in a .mkv 1080p format through VLC on my laptop.  Everything runs fine except for every couple minutes while the file is playing, the video becomes really pixelated.

If I continue letting it play, it corrects itself after about ten seconds.  But if I playback the area where it distorts, it usually plays fine.  But sometimes I have to play it in the same area several time before it removes any distortions.  So I know it's not a problem with the file.  So could it be a video RAM problem?

I'm not sure how much video RAM my laptop has, but seeing as how the video is 1080p, I wouldn't be surprised if it is being filled up.  Can anyone help me identify the problem and help me fix it?

Comment: the problem might be because of your video card! try running a lower resolution SD or 480p movie.. If it runs smoothly then it is because of unsupported devices, i.e. your hardware doesn't have enough speed to render 1080p movie.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking.  I have run lower resolution videos and they run fine.  But then I discovered on OMG Ubuntu that VLC 2.0 had been completed.  So I installed it.  It seems the update fixed the problem.  I watched a full twenty minutes of the same video I was having problems with and I haven't run into a single hick-up.  Thank you for responding!

Comment: We don't do SOLVED on questions, just mark the checkbox next to your answer, thanks!

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 3):

I discovered on OMG Ubuntu that VLC 2.0 had been completed.  After installing it, I watched a full twenty minutes of the same video I was having problems with and I haven't run into a single hick-up.

[How to Install VLC 2.0](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/how-to-install-vlc-2-0-in-ubuntu-10-04-11-10/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on my Lenovo Thinkpad and it just pops up anytime. If your problem is the same as mine then this happens whenever you shake or move your laptop slightly or significantly. These laptops have sensors to sense movement and go into damage control mode just in case the laptop falls. Just try and keep it still and you won't face this problem.